# generating random number in a loop_C++ and arrays in loop (openmp)

Tags: c++, openmp

I have recently learn oenmp and I have two main questions. Consider simple example:

```
 using namespace std;
 std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
 std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unirnd(0, 1);
 int main(){
 double eta=something;
 double x[N],y[N];
 //initializing x[] and y[]...
 for (i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
 double z= unirnd(gen) * eta;
 x[i] = some function of x[i] and y[i] and z
 }
 }
```

I did as below:

```
using namespace std;
 std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
 std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unirnd(0, 1);
 int main(){
 double eta=something;
 double x[N],y[N];
 //initializing x[] and y[]...
 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
      double z = unirnd(gen) * eta;
      x[i] = some function of x[i] and y[i] and z
     }
     }
```

1. Does above code causes data race or another problem as x and y are shared variables?
2. Could random number which is created in the foor loop cause any problem?  If yes, how can I avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet have data races, but not because of `x` and `y`. The race is on the random number generator.

Data race occurs if and only if there is concurrent access to the same object (memory location) *and* one of the access is a write (modification).

Since access to the array subobjects of `x` and `y` are mutually exclusive, no data race occurs here. The random number generator will always mutate its state on generation, and thus is a data race.

Comment: How can I avoid that?

Comment: What do you mean by "The random number generator will always mutate its state on generation, and thus is a data race"?

Comment: I want different random numbers for different index i. Does it generates the same random number for different i's? if not, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @stackcoder How you avoid it is beyond the scope of an answer. The random number generator have internal states (member variables), and when you generate a random number, it changes.

Comment: but random number is defined inside the parallel block and it is a private variable.

Comment: @stackcoder You generated the number _from_ a random number generator. You may imagine the random number generator similar to a simple counter that increments itself every time you generated a number from it. The generated number is of course free from data race, but the counter itself is racing

Comment: But if the counter causes data race, t could also occurs in the first example. I can not underestand how is it related to paralleling the loop

Comment: There is no data race when there is no concurrent access. A simple loop will never be a data race

Comment: But I think c++11 prevent threads to acces the random numbers in a concurrent way

Comment: Also, probability that two different threads access the random generator exactly in the same time is not too much for my case in which I have only 8 threads. Am I correct?

Comment: Probability is irrelevant, data races are always undefined behaviour.

Comment: Could you provide a solution to this problem please?

Comment: @stackcoder I can't. Synchronizing access to objects really is too broad. You may find some links useful: [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: an other option is to simply use a thread safe random number generator